# Can I freeze dried rice noodles after they've been rehydrated?

Tags: freezing, rice, noodles

I'm on a diet and am eating a lot of stir-frys. I use very thin dried rice noodles. Because I only want a specific amount, which is hard to judge when I pull the noodles apart, can I freeze them once they've been rehydrated? Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have a scale?

Comment: I do Catija but I was just curious as to wether I could cook a batch in one go and have it all weighed out seperatly then freeze

Comment: I don't ever have any luck storing rice noodles without having them turn to mush... but I haven't tried much.

Comment: you might be able to use 'em to make little rice balls  (Tang yuan, Nuomici, etc) .  (either intentionally, or by accident by just leaving them sitting around as they bind together on their own)

Comment: I can't see them freezing well, sadly.  I think they will totally turn to mush in the freezer after you thaw them.

Comment: I think it depends on the brand/type of rice noodle, and how much you rehydrate them by. Only way to know for sure is to try it and see what happens. If it doesn't work out, it's not a big loss

Answer (score 2):

As a Professor who teaches Asian Cuisines, I can assure you that rice noodles cannot be frozen. If you were to freeze them that would disintegrate immediately after hitting the water. 
If you do have extra rice noodles consider using them in a noodle salad. There are many wonderful rice noodles salads that you can make with little effort.